# PL-embeddings of balls into PL-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Let $B$ be $k$-dimensional PL-ball and let $M$ be a connected  $n$-dimensional PL-manifold, let's say without boundary. Furthermore let $f,g\colon B\to M$ be two PL-embeddings.
If $k=n$, then the disc theorem (see Theorem 3.34 in Rourke-Sanderson) says that, after possibly composing $f$ by a reflection, $f$ and $g$ are ambiently isotopic.

Now assume that $k<n$. Is it true that $f$ and $g$ are necessarily ambiently isotopic?

If we work in the smooth category, then the answer would be yes. But I am very unsure about the PL-category.

Comment: If you take the cones over two distinct knots in $S^3$ you get two non-isotopic embedding of $D^2$ into $\mathbb R^4$.

Comment: Hmm. Yes. The issue is, why are they non-isotopic? I think what you are driving at is the following delicate question: given a PL-embedded disk $D$ (or surface) and a point $P$ on the disk, to what degree is the link of $P$ well-defined. More precisely, if you have two PL-balls $E$ and $F$ around $P$, are the isotopy types of $D\cap \partial E$ and $D\cap \partial F$ the same?

Comment: I am not sure whether I can convince myself that this is the case, but I think I can show that if $D$ is the cone on a non-trivial knot, then for every 4-ball $E$ containing the cone point the intersection $D\cap \partial E$ is a non-trivial knot, which is enough to show that it is not a standard PL-embedding. So I think one can get examples that way but I am not quite sure how to prove  the statement you give in full generality.

Comment: The link of a point is a piecewise-linear invariant object, it should be so also for the pair $(\mathbb R^4, D^2)$, for which the link of a point is a pair $(S^3, K)$ for some knot $K\subset S^3$. I suppose that Rourke-Sanderson should contain a proof. So it should be invariant by any PL homeomorphism of $\mathbb R^4$. There are many "shoulds"...

Comment: I did convince myself at some point of the fact that the cone on a non-trivial knot is not  topologically locally flat (and I should have remembered that this basically already answers my question),  but the argument I used involved looking at fundamental groups. But perhaps in the PL-category it is more clear. I find the PL-category confusing, since I have a hard time separating cartoons ("looks convincing in my picture") from proper statements in the literature.

Comment: Anyway, thanks, you answered my question!

Comment: Usually the book of Rourke-Sanderson is a very useful reference for proper statements. It's only 120 pages, but it contains a lot of foundation stuff. I am grateful this book exists, especially now, since it seems to me that PL topology is not so widely well-known as it was before (although it is very powerful, in my opinion).

Comment: It turns out that it follows from the discussion on page 51 of Rourke-Sanderson that the cones on different knots are indeed inequivalent. So now I am completely satisfied.

Comment: Just a remark that Hudson is also often a very useful reference about the PL category. Of course Rourke-Sanderson is also great, but I've sometimes needed results they don't have that Hudson does, especially about noncompact things.

Answer (score 3):

The precise result you want is Theorem 4.20 (page 56) in Rourke-Sanderson's book.

[image]

The notations in the statement are on page 50, but they are self-explanatory, e.g., $I^{n,q}$ is the standard disk pair ($n$-disk, $q$-disk), and you are assuming that $M^{n,q}$ is a closed manifold.

Comment: I'm not sure this quite addresses the original question, since in this theorem it seems that both I and M are n-dimensional but the question asks for the dimension of the domain ball to be smaller than the dimension of M.

Comment: @GregFriedman: I think the point is that if $R$ is a regular neighborhood of an locally flat $k$-disk $D$, then $(R, D)$ is a standard ball pair. I agree that this requires a proof, so I was hasty.  I will search for a better reference.

Comment: I see. But I don't think the original question requires the embedding to be locally flat. In fact, it looks like it's been determined in the comments that the lack of local flatness does pose an obstruction.

Comment: @GregFriednab This just means that one has to require local flatness.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Bruno's comment I think it would be interesting if we consider the following more general result, which is Theorem 4.4.2 in [[Daverman-Venema's book]](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/davenema.pdf).

**Theorem.** Suppose $X$ is a compact, $k$-dimensional space and $M$ is
a PL $n$-manifold, where $n \geq 5$ and $2k + 2 \leq n$. If $\lambda_0, \lambda_1 : X \to M$ are two topological embeddings whose images are 1-LCC in $M$ and $f_t : X \to M$
is a homotopy between $\lambda_0$ and $\lambda_1$, then there exists a compactly supported
ambient isotopy $\Psi$ of $M$ such that $\Psi_0 = \text{Id}_M$ and $\Psi_1\lambda_0 = \lambda_1$.